# Chapter* shows the previous page title

Tags: numbering

I have the list of figures and after that I would like to insert a chapter (not-numbered, `\chapter*`)

```
\listoffigures
\chapter*{Abstract}
text
```

The problem is that by using `\chapter*` the following pages have as page heading "List of Figures" while they should have Abstract.
[image]

Is there any way to force to have "Abstract" instead of "List of Figures" ?

Comment: please provide a minimal working example

Comment: You can vote to close this question. The suggested duplicated solves it.